What should I do to pass this React custom hook test?
"I'm new to testing. I've been attempting to test my custom hook, but despite encountering numerous errors, I still haven't been able to pass the test. The hook simply utilizes the useQuery hook to return an API response, but it consistently returns 'undefined.' Any suggestions, please?"
export const retrieveData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/jaime/')
  //   console.log(response)
  return response.data
}

// This is the hook I would like to test:
export function useJaime() {
  const {
    data: jaimeRamirez,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = useQuery('DadosDoJaime', retrieveData)

  return { jaimeRamirez, error, isLoading }
}

This is the test so far:
const infoJaime = {
  nombre: 'Jaime Ramírez',
  compania: 'Microsoft',
  coche: 'Porsche',
}

const createWrapper = () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()
  return ({ children }) => (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

describe('Testando hooks customizados: ', () => {
  test('useJaime', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useJaime(), {
      wrapper: createWrapper(),
    })

    act(() => {
      expect(result.current.jaimeRamirez).toEqual(infoJaime)
    })
  })
})


Any help would be highly appreciated,
Thanks in advance
I've been trying to work with async functions, but no success at all.

First you need to mock your response data coming from axios
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');
axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: infoJaime });

Then you can make some assertions like this
expect(result.current.jaimeRamirez).toEqual(infoJaime)

But make sure those are asynchronous
Complete code
jest.mock('axios');

describe('Testando hooks customizados: ', () => {
  test('useJaime', async () => {
    axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: infoJaime });

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useJaime(), {
      wrapper: createWrapper(),
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.jaimeRamirez).toEqual(infoJaime));
  });
}); 


Thank you very much, Sanka! It worked for me. :) But why did I have to mock the axios and why did waitFor need to be asynchronous, please?

My idea is if we mock our API calls(especially POST, PUT, DELETE) there is no effect on the data in our databases. The reason for the waitFor is we mocking axios.get() as a Promise because actually axios.get() return a Promise. I use https://mswjs.io/ to mock API calls if I do unit testing.
